# ANDROID - "The id "example" is defined but not assigned to any views"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-styles

I defined ID in ids.xml -> `<item name="example" type="id"/>`

I used this ID in styles.xml like this ->

```
<style name="exampleStyle">
     <item name="android:id">@id/example</item>
     ###rest of items (width, height etc.)
</style>
```

And i used this style in my ConstraintLayout like this ->

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/goNextButton"/>

    <ImageView
        style="@style/exampleStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Finally IDE (Android studio) shows error "The id example is defined but not assigned to any views.

Why it doesn't see that i used this id just via styles? Can i fix this without using `tools:ignore="UnknownId` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "`android:id`" in style use this in `ImageView`

For an example in side a layout it may have several `ImageView`. So you can use same style several times. But if action is based on id then you can't use this properly.